# NGINX redirecting subdomains to document root of root domain when using wildcard LetsEncrypt cert

Tags: ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

I have an EC2 instance running NGINX and I've set up a wildcard LetsEncrypt certificate that covers subdomains. It doesn't actually redirect the domain name (e.g. `test.example.com` doesn't redirect to `example.com`. It stays as `test.example.com` but shows the document root of `example.com`).

I'm pretty sure my DNS is set up correctly because, when I remove my 301 redirects and put the root in the first server block, all my subdomains work correctly leading me to believe that the SSL cert is the issue.

Here's my NGINX config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name example.com;

  return 301 https://example.com;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;

  root /var/www/html/example.com;

  index index.html;

  ssl_certificate /home/webadmin/letsencrypt/config/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /home/webadmin/letsencrypt/config/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name test.example.com;

    return 301 https://test.example.com;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    root /var/www/html/test.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /home/webadmin/letsencrypt/config/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/webadmin/letsencrypt/config/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your example config you don't have `server_name` for your SSL `server` blocks but do for your `http` `server` blocks. So `nginx` knows what you are talking about for the 301 redirects but `nginx` will pick the first server block that matches the port / protocol if it does not match a `server_name`